# How to show the each levels with different color in sunburst chart?

Tags: anychart

I have created a sunburst chart with the help of the Anychart library. Now I want to fill different colors on each level. Like blue color background in all slice of level-1. all data is coming dynamically from SQL. How I can do this?[Sample image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHIz4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors of the children in Sunburst chart are inherited from the parent. It means the only way to achieve what you want is to set them for each point in the data. Please check this sample: https://playground.anychart.com/997YGRTI